# Where is this error coming from: Status Code 500: "Can't Set Headers After They've Already been Set" using fetch API

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

Can anyone tell me where the error is coming from? This bug is killing my flow. I'm using NodeJs with Express in Webstorm.

```
app.post('/getData', function(req, res) {
    debugger;
    var data = req.body;
    console.log(data);
    toSend = data;
    var formFields = {};
    res.send({msg: "Success"});
    var endPoint = 'https://secure.p01.eloqua.com/API/REST/2.0/assets/form/' + toSend["formID"].toString();

    var myInit = {
        method: "get",
        headers: {'Authorization': authenticationHeader, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        cache: 'default'
    }

    fetch(endPoint,myInit)
        .then(function (data) {
            formFields = data;
            console.log(formFields['elements']);
        });
});
```

Comment: why are using send before you run the fetch?

Comment: Try putting the `res.send()` at the end of the function

Comment: @LucaKiebel it should be when fetch is done....

Comment: The `Can't Set Headers After They've Already been Set` error is probably happening because you have added an error handler to your routes and you are getting an error in you function after `send()`. The handler tries to send a 500 error, but you've already responded. There should be another error in the console above this one.

Comment: Also, how are you using Fetch? Did you install node-fetch?

Comment: @LucaKiebel I just tried that and instead of the "can't set headers ..." error I just got: POST /getData 500 25211.558 ms - 1365

Comment: What's in the Node console?

Comment: @Mark_M just installed node-fetch. now I have this lol: POST /getData - - ms - -

Comment: @Mark_M No other error codes though

Comment: @JimMortenson it's something

Comment: If it's not writing to the console, you should add a `catch()` to the fetch and see if you're getting errors there.

Comment: `fetch(...)
    .then(function(response) {
        /* logic */       
    }).then(function(){
      res.send(...)
   }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
      /* return error.... */
    });`